# How to load a new template page according to a particular URL?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization, theme-development

I want to load some of the pages(not wordpress page, a template file other than wordpress's default template file) according to the url came on the address bar.

for instance, I have page in my template file ie my_account.php to show my profile pic and other informations from to my wordpress pofile. and it is placed in my defaut theme folder

```
/themes/mytheme/my_account.php
```

When the url is `http://mysite/MyAccount/` then I need to load the above page. 
Something like if `http://mysite/register/` then load the register.php from my theme folder.

I'm using custome permalinks option. `http://mysite/hello_world_post/`

So How can I configure and load the template  according to the url, how to controll this by using a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use template_redirect. I haven't tested it though, should be something like this.

```
function page_redirect() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'your_url')  {

        require(TEMPLATEPATH . '/mY-account.php');

    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'page_redirect');
```

Comment: Thanks for the updates, after a long search I did exactly same as above just 3hour before.

Comment: Was trying to figure out how to do something like this and thanks to this answer it is now solved

Comment: @coderex et al wouldn't you have to disable WordPress from flagging this unknown URL (within your existing rewrite rules) and returning 404?  eg, by adding new query vars or hijacking $wp_query->is_404 .  or were you successful otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Templates_by_page-ID_or_page-Slug

The easiest is by slug. For example if your http://mysite/register/ slug is register then create a custom page template page-register.php.

BTW, I didn't know you can use _ for permalink? Plugin?

Comment: In this case I need to create a page from my admin area, But I don't want to do that. Is there any method to achieve this??

Comment: Just create a blank Pages. Put in title and slug with no content. It will load the template. BTW, if you still don't want to create from admin, I think there's a plugin called Fake Page.